# Search for a variable string within a string

Tags: excel

This is the actual problem: I have this text in A1:

> The Gross Return of the S&P index over the past year has been 5%. The ISIN for this Gross Return is CH354892. The ISIN for Net Return is CH875621.

I want to write a general function that would return the ISIN for Gross Return, which is `CH354892`. I was thinking of searching for the words `Gross Return` and `ISIN` and if the difference of the positions between them is < 35, I would grab the text starting five positions after `Gross Return` and ending at eight positions after the start.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The first `is` seems equally distinctive:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" is ",A1)+4,8)
```